# May I create logger in Log4j2 per Level, not per class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I was taking over an old java projcet. And the original designer has gone.
In this project, it uses Log4j in a static way, like this:

```
public class LogUtil {
private static final String FQCN = LogUtil.class.getName();
private static final Logger logger1 = Logger.getLogger("INFO");
private static final Logger logger2 = Logger.getLogger("ERROR");

public static void info(Object message) {
    if (logger1.isInfoEnabled()) {
        forcedLog(logger1, Level.INFO, message);
    }
}


public static void error(Object message) {
    forcedLog(logger2, Level.ERROR, message);
}


private static void forcedLog(Logger logger, Level level, Object message) {
    logger.callAppenders(new LoggingEvent(FQCN, logger, level, message, null));
}
```

}

Then other class can easily write logs with `LogUtil.error("")` and `LogUtil.info("")` .
And the INFO logger and ERROR logger were configured to write in separate files.

But in Log4j2, the class LoggingEvent can not be found.

So the question is, if I want to use Log4j2, how should I modify this class?
(maybe use  Log4j 1.x bridge provided in log4j2 packages?)

Is using logger in this way reasonable? It seems that it is easier than creating loggers per class. Is there any problems like performance or others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is, if I want to use Log4j2, how should I modify this class? (maybe use Log4j 1.x bridge provided in log4j2 packages?)

You ***could*** rewrite it to use the public API instead of relying on underlying implementation details. So, something like this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LogUtil {
    private static final Logger TRACE_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("TRACE");
    private static final Logger DEBUG_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("DEBUG");
    private static final Logger INFO_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("INFO");
    private static final Logger WARN_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("WARN");
    private static final Logger ERROR_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("ERROR");
    private static final Logger FATAL_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("FATAL");

    public static void trace(Object msg){
        TRACE_LOGGER.trace(msg);
    }

    public static void debug(Object msg){
        DEBUG_LOGGER.debug(msg);
    }

    public static void info(Object msg) {
        INFO_LOGGER.info(msg);
    }

    public static void warn(Object msg){
        WARN_LOGGER.warn(msg);
    }

    public static void error(Object msg) {
        ERROR_LOGGER.error(msg);
    }

    public static void fatal(Object msg){
        FATAL_LOGGER.fatal(msg);
    }
    ...
}
```

> Is using logger in this way reasonable? It seems that it is easier than creating loggers per class. Is there any problems like performance or others?

I don't see how adding 3 lines to a class is anything other than easy. All it takes to create a logger (in log4j2) is this:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
...
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
```

As for potential problems, with this implementation you give up a lot of the functionality of log4j.

1. You can't change the log level on a package or class basis because all of the classes share the same loggers. Perhaps you want to turn on TRACE logging for a new class you're working on, but you don't want any TRACE logs from other classes as it clutters the log file - you would not be able to make this kind of change easily.
2. You can't change the appenders on a package or class basis because once again all classes share the same loggers. Perhaps you want to send all of the logs from a new package that you're working on to a separate file so that you can more easily see what your new code is doing without having to filter the logs manually. Maybe you want to see all logs from a particular class or package in a single file during development so that you can follow the execution more easily without having to jump around to different files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just as you said, one logger per class to more flexible to control the log printed by some classes.

Comment: I tried your first way, but the logs trace were all like
`LogUtil.info(LogUtil.java:23) test`
The real place call LogUtil.info was not being printed to logs.
To record the real place of log, it seems I have to call logger.info() directly.
I thought to create logger by
`logger = LogManager.getLogger(ClassA.class);`
So it may took some time to implement in every class with class' name.
I'll try your way, and replace all LogUtil.info() to logger.info().
Thanks.

Comment: I see what you mean regarding using the class name in the logger declaration. log4j2 provides the `getLogger()` method that takes zero parameters. See [log4j2 API documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html) - see the last section about "Logger Names"

Comment: Regarding the file name and line number issue yes that would be a problem with the first approach I suggested. In fairness you didn't say that you were printing the file names and line numbers (most people concerned with performance would not since it does impact performance). So this would be another reason not to use loggers in the manner that you had been before as this adds more complexity to your problem.